# Open Tab(Ordered List) on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm following an example to make tabbed content with HTML and Javascript. Linked here.

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_tabs

With this example I'd like the London Tab to open once the page is loaded. I've played around with the Active/Non active class in the Javascript code but can't seem to figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>Click on the links inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cud accept  and upvote answers you found useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger a automatic click on that element after Page is Loaded:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("default_city_link").click();
});
```

**WORKING SNIPPET:**

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("default_city_link").click();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
ul.tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.tab li {
  float: left;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */

ul.tab li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
/* Create an active/current tablink class */

ul.tab li a:focus,
.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the links inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#" id="default_city_link" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run your code when the document is ready, like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      openCity(event, 'London')
});


function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger click event on first tab by calling `click()` function. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Click on the links inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
  
document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks')[0].click();
</script>

</body>
```